# Replacing all letters in Excel

Tags: excel, replace, excel-2013

I have cells with values like `01EL041` in Excel and I would like to replace all letters with a fixed character (in my case, `0`, leaving `01041` in this example). Is there a good way to do this without VBScript? I know I could do 26 `SUBSTUITUTE`s but that seems terrible.

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: By "all letters," do you mean you want to replace the "E" and "L," (and/or whatever other letters) with "0" leaving a result of 0100041?

Comment: @ScottCraner 2013

Comment: @Scott Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use this array formula:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

for prior versions that do not have CONCAT you can use this array formula:

```
=TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),0)*10^(LEN(A1)-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))))),REPT("0",LEN(A1)))
```

Again, being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Neat trick (+1)! Unfortunately I have 2013, any ideas that would work there?

Comment: O365 covers both 2013 and 2016 so it should work in 2013 without problems.

Comment: @EmilBorconi but one does need a subscription to O365

Comment: @ScottCraner I managed to make a fool out of my self twice in a period of less than 5 mins, embarrassed with myself... On a second note, that formula is some serious craft...

Comment: @ScottCraner Ingenious solution. Only thing I would change is remove volatile functions, i.e. replace `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))` with `ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))`.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 habits are hard to break,  that is good, never thought of that, and I should have.

Comment: @ScottCraner The irony is that you have pointed out to me in many other posts to remove volatile functions when I used `INDIRECT`. Just returning the favor now :P

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I get blinded by habit.  when I wanted to iterate numbers I always used some form of ROW(INDIRECT()) it is what I learned and never questioned after learning to shun the volatility of INDIRECT.  I never separated the two functions till now.  Even us old dogs can learn a new trick here and there. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No need of VB.

Simple, press Ctrl+H (fro replace) in the search write ? and replace it with whatever you want.

**EDIT**

If by all letters you mean any character than this is the easiest way, if not please refer to Scott's answer.